# Neuralnet training results negative output

Tags: r, neural-network, normalization, training-data

I am using neuralnet package in r to predict discharge of a river with five input variables.

'df' is the dataframe with original data with six columns, first five column as input and the last as output.
Data are normalized in range 0 to 1 using RSNNS package

```
library(RSNNS)
norm_data <- data.frame(normalizeData(df, type = "0_1"))
```

first 2557 (seven years) data are used as training set

```
trn_data <- norm_data[1:2557,]
```

neuralnet structure is

```
library(neuralnet)
trn <- neuralnet(discharge~rain+temp+humid+sun+d_disch,trn_data,hidden = 10, threshold = 0.01)
```

I am using Nash–Sutcliffe coefficient to assess the training efficiency of neuralnet which for the above structure yields to be quite satisfactory 0.8414. However, the training result (`trn$net.result`) contains some negative outputs.  Total 152 results were found to be less than zero, which however are very close to zero, and replacement of these values with zero has no significant impact on the Nash coefficient (0.8418 vs 0.8414).
For reference, here is the summary of negative output

```
Min.         1st Qu.          Median            Mean         3rd Qu. 
-0.008131191000 -0.002250917000 -0.001022112000 -0.001596980000 -0.000471144100 
           Max. 
-0.000000928481
```

I tried testing the model with various sets of test data (both test and training data  are subset, 75% training & 25% test, of a data set normalized with the same pattern) but the model does not perform satisfactorily (Nash less than 40%). The test output contains even larger negative values.

My question here is: Although the training data are bound between 0 to 1 why is the training result negative? How does this affect the performance of model while testing? And, how is this fixed? Thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't have experience with this package, but looking at the formula within the `neuralnet` function, I believe your `discharge` variable is a continuous variable. In theory, a continuous variable could range anywhere on the real line (from negative infinity to positive infinity). There is nothing telling the neural net to constrain the response to `[0, 1]`. To resolve this issue, if you really want your predictions to be in `[0, 1]`, you could just constrain your predictions to `[0, 1]` manually, or perhaps apply a transformation to the response before putting it into the neural network.

Comment: The transformation could be, for example, a logit transformation `log(discharge/(1-discharge))` (this will give you a prediction between 0 and 1). Then once you get your predicted values, you can then reverse the transformation by doing `exp(pred)/(1 + exp(pred))`.

Comment: thanx @jav for the comment. neuralnet function employs a sigmoid function 'f(x) = 1/(1+exp(-x)' to transfer the input signal in hidden and output nodes which is bounded between 0 to 1.

Comment: @H.Paudel, did you find the solution of your problem? I have the same problem too. I will be very glad if you share the solution.